# Is it possible to combine homebrews "brew list" with another command or argument to get the short description on all installed packages?

Tags: homebrew

I want the short description in combination with `brew list` or `brew list --cask` like in [/api/formula.json](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/) on my installed brew packages.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`brew desc $(brew list)`

or formatted in columns with

`brew desc --eval-all $(brew list) | awk 'gsub(/^([^:]*?)\s*:\s*/,"&=")' | column -s "=" -t`

does the trick. thanks to carlocab:

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/14244#issuecomment-1346909437